# after insert no return anything but data have been save

Tags: javascript, php

```
<?php

$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$password="";
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","recipe");


 if ($_GET['type'] == "upload") 
{
   $title=$_GET['title'];
   $creator=$_GET['creator'];
   $ingredient=$_GET['ingredient'];
   $serving=$_GET['serving'];
   $note=$_GET['note'];
   $prepare=$_GET['prepare'];

    $insertsql = "INSERT INTO upload (title,creator,ingredient,serving,note,prepare)
           VALUE ('$title','$creator','$ingredient','$serving','$note','$prepare')";


if(mysql_query($insertsql,$db))
           {echo 1;  }
else
           {echo 0;  }


      }

     ?> 

      <script>
    $.ajax({
    type : "get",
    url : "dataconn.php",
    data :              "type=upload&title="+title+"&prepare="+prepare+"&creator="+creator+"&ingredient="+ingredien  t+"&serving="+serving+"&note="+note,
    success : function(data){
        alert(data);


    }
});

 </script>
 </head>
 </html>
```

When I pass variable in to PHP from JavaScript it able to save in database but I need some value like the data have been successful save and will come out a alert 1 or 0.

But once I connect to database it cant alert any more. Like some error blocking in database but still can save just does not come out any alert. If I remove it then it running all

It does not sure alert as well.

Comment: You're mixing MySQL APIs. They do **not** mix. Fix this line `(mysql_query($insertsql,$db)` Plus, you're calling the wrong connection variable.

Comment: @Fred-ii- meant it should be `mysqli_query` instead of `mysql_query`

Comment: i have use mysqli aswell 'mysql_query($con,$insertsql)' but the problem still same

Comment: `mysql_query($con,$insertsql)` that's not `mysqli_`

Comment: Here `mysqli_query($con,$insertsql)`

Comment: i have try this before `mysqli_query($con,$insertsql)` but still cant alert back 1 or 0

Comment: It may be inside your JS that's failing then; seems like it and that is not my strong point; couldn't help you there. Might even be in your form. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` might help.

Comment: The spaces in `+ingredien  t+` may also be a contributing factor.

Comment: @JakeGould I just noticed it now.

Comment: @JakeGould A noble effort at that. OP needs to learn the basics of SQL then move on to gradual upgrades of the fancy stuff. All the more reasons I don't put in answers anymore; too many things stand to go wrong. Sometimes trying to help someone for an hour or more, is ridiculous and unfortunately, it doesn't pay the bills. I don't mind helping out, but this question has too many things wrong with it. I hope OP accepts your answer; I have no way to test it. Cheers ;-) I voted to close btw and is one heckuva can 'o worms.

Comment: This question seems to have no possible (correct) answers, given the efforts already put in. Do start by reading and understanding the basics of SQL http://www.mysqltutorial.org/ before trying to attempt an advanced feature such as AJAX/JS. This question should be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
if(mysql_query($insertsql,$db))
```

To this line; using `mysqli_*` extensions and correctly using `$con` for the query instead of `$db` which is a connection variable you don’t have set anywhere:

```
if(mysqli_query($con,$insertsql))
```

Also, you should set your MySQL calls to return errors like this:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","recipe") or die(mysqli_connect_errno());
```

And change this as well:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$insertsql) or die(mysqli_connect_errno());

if ($result) {
  echo 1;
}
else {
   echo 0;
}
```

Also you are using `VALUE` in the query when it should be `VALUES`:

```
$insertsql = "INSERT INTO upload (title,creator,ingredient,serving,note,prepare)
       VALUES ('$title','$creator','$ingredient','$serving','$note','$prepare')";
```

Not to mention in your JavaScript AJAX code you have `+ingredien  t+` when it should be `+ingredien t+`:

```
data : "type=upload&title="+title+"&prepare="+prepare+"&creator="+creator+"&ingredient="+ingredient+"&serving="+serving+"&note="+note,
```

At the top why are you setting variables for the MySQL connection but then putting values inline?

```
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$password="";
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","recipe");
```

And finally, I did a cleanup of your main MySQL logic code. I have included [`mysqli_stmt_bind_param`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), [`mysqli_free_result`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php) & [`mysqli_close`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php) and set a `foreach` loop for `$_GET` values. This simply should work:

```
// Credentials.
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$password="";

// Connecting, selecting database
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, 'recipe') or die(mysqli_connect_errno());

if (isset($_GET['type']) && !empty($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type'] == "upload") {

  // Set a '$_GET' array and roll through each value.
  $get_array = array('title', 'creator', 'ingredient', 'serving', 'note', 'prepare');
  foreach ($get_array as $get_key => $get_value) {
    $$get_value = isset($_GET[$get_value]) && !empty($_GET[$get_value]) ? $_GET[$get_value] : null;
  }

  // Set the query.
  $insertsql = "INSERT INTO `upload` (`title`, `creator`, `ingredient`, `serving`, `note`, `prepare`)"
             . " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
             ;

  // Bind the params.
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($insertsql, 'ssssss', $title, $creator, $ingredient, $serving, $note, $prepare);

  // Run the query.
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $insertsql) or die(mysqli_connect_errno());

  if ($result) {
    echo 1;
  }
  else {
    echo 0;
  }

  // Free the result set.
  mysqli_free_result($result);

  // Close the connection.
  mysqli_close($con);

}
```

Comment: i have try this before but the problem still same
i cant alert anything because of the connection database

Comment: i have try mysqli_query($con,$insertsql) this as well but still cant alert back the 1 or 0

Comment: just try but it still not working .this problem aldy face 1 day

Comment: *"Also you are using VALUE in the query when it should be VALUES:"* Oh for crying outloud lol I never spotted that. However, the spaces in `+ingredien  t+` may also be a contributing factor.

Comment: but the data can be save in database just wan to alert that 0 or 1 if successful stock only
i have also try this before but still same

Comment: what to put in ?,?,?,?
izit $title,$creater?